# Enable SMB file sharing on OS X - "Incorrect Password"

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard, network-shares, active-directory

I have a Mac running Snow Leopard connected to an Active Directory domain. I can share folders on the Mac and view files from Windows without problems.

When I try to enable my Mac account for write access through System Preferences, I'm prompted for my account's password. Even though I'm entering the right one, I get an "Incorrect Password" response. The same process works fine for the local Mac administrator account; it's the Active Directory account I'm having problems with.

I followed the advice on [this page on apple.com](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh1161.html) without success: (I used the Mac to reset my domain password, and re-created my login keychain)

> If you want to use a user account that existed before you installed Mac OS X 10.3 (Panther), you may need to reset the password for the account using Accounts preferences.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong? Until I fix this I can't write to my Mac file share from Windows.

**Edit:** Although I never resolved the problem on Snow Leopard, it's fine on Lion.

Comment: I've attached the answer for prosperity. I got hit with this bug in Mavericks and it took forever to stumble upon the fix. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if I'm not getting this correctly, but the problem seems to be a blockage in the process of enabling write privileges on a folder. It appears that you have successfully turned on SMB sharing, and Windows users can connect, but whatever login account that you're using has read only privileges to the desired folder.

If that is the case, a relatively easy alternative might be to change the permissions on the desired folder with chmod in the Terminal using an ACL.